# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_SL on line 23

Tags: php

I am getting this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected
>   T_SL on line 23

Here is line 23:

```
$selectorder = <<<ORDER
```

Here it is in context:

```
$grid->setUrl('myfirstgrid.php');

$selectorder = <<<ORDER 
function(rowid, selected) 
{ 
    if(rowid != null) { 
        alert("selected: "+rowid); 
    } 
} 
ORDER;
$grid->setGridEvent('onSelectRow', $selectorder);
```

What is causing this error?

I personally don't know what `<<<` does and have never used it, I got it from a tutorial. I tried to google it, but you can't google characters like that :(

Comment: For other people who've got this error but haven't used heredoc syntax the problem may be because a subversion conflict message has inserted the same brackets into the file

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Check for whitespace after `<<<ORDER`. There should be no blank characters.

Comment: This is exactly what it was. A single space at end of line 23.

Comment: This answer helped me after similar fruitless web searching for 'php <<<' After fixing my extra space I found the PHP docs specify that the opening identifier must be followed immediately by a newline, see the heredoc section here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: There also should be no semicolon.

Answer (score 5):

`<<<` is for heredoc: [See manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)

Comment: I had a space at end like: "<<<Order " ..thanks for showing me the manual. I would have never figured that out.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that there is no **SPACE/INDENTATION** before ending `ORDER;`

Comment: Clearly the closing identifier is not the problem.

Answer (score 1):

PHP Heredoc does not get on well with the % symbol, and the following also causes `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_SL`:

```
<?php
$var=<<<%%SHRUBBERY%%

Nih!

%%SHRUBBERY%%;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Also make sure that you have 3 '<<<'. Omitting one will throw this error. Also if your using NOWDOCs, make sure your hosting provider has php 5.3 installed. Plus if your php environment is below 5.3, do not use double quotes or single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

It's called "Heredoc syntax", and it lets you specify large strings without using quotes. In this case, it looks like you're using it to put JavaScript code into a variable. Since you started the string with `<<<ORDER`, you should be able to finish it with `ORDER;`, as you have — but you need to make sure that `ORDER;` occurs at the start of a line, with no whitespace before it.