# PHP HTML Heredoc

Tags: php, html

```
<?php
$html = <<< HTM
<h1>This works!</h1>
HTM;

echo $html;

$html2 = <<< HTM2 
<h3>And this don't</h3>
HTM2;

echo $html2;
?>
```

There are two heredocs. The first heredoc does work, the second not. And I don't understand why. Maybe someone can help to figure out this problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3425423/parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-t-sl-on-line-23

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<?php
$html = <<< HTM
<h1>This works!</h1>
HTM;

echo $html;

$html2 = <<< HTM2
<h3>And this don't</h3>
HTM2;

echo $html2;
?>
```

You've got space after HTM2, here: `<<< HTM2`. The space after `<<<` isn't a problem, just the one right after `HTM2` in your example. Remove it and you'll be fine. You should always make sure there is no whitespace around the `heredoc` delimiters. It can be tricky at times. Please refer to the documentation for more information: [PHP Heredoc Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc).